# Is a local client passed a direct reference to a EJB LocalBean?

Tags: ejb, ejb-3.1

When a local client gets a reference to a `LocalBean`, does the container provide a direct reference to bean instance? If not, what is provided?

Pointers to specs and authentic sources would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The spec does not prescribe that explicitly as I see, but injected references to EJBs are normally interface-based proxies. That's necessary for providing container services, like transaction management and timeout control, picking an instance from the pool in case of SLSB, calling user interceptors if any, etc.

While the spec only tells something rather neutral:

> The container is responsible for making the business interfaces and/or
>   home interfaces of its deployed enterprise beans available to the
>   client through dependency injection and/or through lookup in the JNDI
>   namespace.

You can easily check that BTW, for example with debugger.

Comment: Interesting answer. I thought the specification was clearer on instance reference through proxy. Otherwise, it would not be possible, in my view, the container would not have the control that is necessary to perform its actions.